# Why do Unix passwords use the system time and PID for the salt value?

Tags: unix, passwords

I don't understand why the PID and time is used. I guess the time is to help randomize the salt, and I suppose the PID does as well? Isn't there a chance a lot of other uses could have the same PID?

Comment: I wasn't aware that this is how the salt was generated for Unix passwords.  Do you have a reference to support the statement that Unix password salts are generated in this way?  The method described is relatively insecure, for what that's worth;  Salts should be random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two processes with the same Process ID at the same time.

Comment: Ahh well put! I didn't think of that :)

Comment: Actually, this is pretty much already implicit in the word *identifier* (ID). If there could be two of them, it wouldn't be much of an identifier, would it?

Comment: Isn't the salt+pid used to keep track of account creation time?

Comment: While true, this doesn't strictly help, as the resolution of a timestamp is often limited to about 1 second (and always finite), and the creation / destruciton of processes is fast and not limited in the same way (AFAIK).